# How to dispatch a change action in input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently making a small form for an important assignment which demands redux. I want to create a global object which dynamically updates itself after onChange. How do I update the changes in the global object on changing input so I can use it any where ?

here are my files
Details.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import {useSelector , useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {setUser} from './Redux/actions';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    minWidth: 400,
    margin: "20px",
  },
  bullet: {
    display: "inline-block",
    margin: "0 2px",
    transform: "scale(0.8)",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  text: {
    width: 300,
    margin: "10px",
  },
});

export default function Details() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const bull = <span className={classes.bullet}>•</span>;
  const [user , setUsers] = useState({
    username:"",
    email:"",
    phone:0,
    age:0,
    month:"",
    batch:"",
    isPaid:0
  })

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setUsers({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          color="textSecondary"
          variant="h5"
          gutterBottom
        >
          Enter Your Details
        </Typography>
        <TextField
          id="filled-basic"
          label="Full Name"
          variant="filled"
          name = "name"
          className={classes.text}
          onChange = {handleChange}
        />
        <TextField
          id="filled-basic"
          label="Phone number"
          variant="filled"
          name = "phone"
          className={classes.text}
          onChange = {handleChange}
        />
        <TextField
          id="filled-basic"
          label="Email"
          variant="filled"
          name = "email"
          className={classes.text}
          onChange = {handleChange}
        />
        <TextField
          id="filled-basic"
          label="Age"
          variant="filled"
          name = "age"
          className={classes.text}
          onChange = {handleChange}
        />
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

actions.js

```
export  const SET_USER_PROFILE = 'SET_USER_PROFILE';

export const setUser = name => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type:SET_USER_PROFILE,
        payload:name
    })
}
```

reducers.js

```
import { SET_USER_PROFILE } from "./actions";

const initialState = {
    
}

function userReducer(state = initialState , action){
    switch(action.type){
        case SET_USER_PROFILE:
            return {...state , name:action.payload};
        
        default:
            return state;
    }

}

export default userReducer;
```

store.js

```
import {legacy_createStore as createStore , combineReducers , applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

import userReducer from './reducers'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({userReducer});

export const Store = createStore(rootReducer , applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are asking how to convert from using local component state to redux state.

1. Move the `username`, `email`, `phone`, and `age` state into the `userReducer` function's `initialState`.

   ```javascript
   const initialState = {
     username: "",
     email: "",
     phone: "",
     age: ""
   };
   ```
2. Update `userReducer` to consume an action payload that contains the key and value for the nested state you want to update.

   ```javascript
   const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
       case SET_USER_PROFILE:
         const { key, value } = action.payload;
         return { ...state, [key]: value };

       default:
         return state;
     }
   };
   ```
3. Update the `setUser` action creator function to take the `key` and `value` you want to update and return the action payload. There's no asynchronous logic here so there's no need to write a Thunk function that is also passed the `dispatch` function.

   ```
   const setUser = (key, value) => ({
     type: SET_USER_PROFILE,
     payload: { key, value }
   });
   ```
4. Update the `Details` component to select the `user` state from Redux and update the `handleChange` callback to dispatch the `setUser` action with the appropriate payload values. Since these are likely supposed to be *controlled* inputs you'll want/need to specify the `value` prop on the fields and pass the appropriate state.

   ```
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const { username, email, phone, age } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

   const handleChange = (e) => {
     const { name, value } = e.target;
     dispatch(setUser(name, value));
   };

   return (
     <Card className={classes.root}>
       <CardContent>
         <Typography
           className={classes.title}
           color="textSecondary"
           variant="h5"
           gutterBottom
         >
           Enter Your Details
         </Typography>
         <TextField
           id="filled-basic"
           label="Full Name"
           variant="filled"
           name="username"
           value={username}
           className={classes.text}
           onChange={handleChange}
         />
         <TextField
           id="filled-basic"
           label="Phone number"
           variant="filled"
           name="phone"
           value={phone}
           className={classes.text}
           onChange={handleChange}
         />
         <TextField
           id="filled-basic"
           label="Email"
           variant="filled"
           name="email"
           value={email}
           className={classes.text}
           onChange={handleChange}
         />
         <TextField
           id="filled-basic"
           label="Age"
           variant="filled"
           name="age"
           value={age}
           className={classes.text}
           onChange={handleChange}
         />
       </CardContent>
     </Card>
   );
   ```

[image: Edit how-to-dispatch-a-change-action-in-input-field]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Drew! It helped a lot, also got to learn some new stuff.

Comment: @Tanvesh Certainly, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!